# How to manage signing keystore in Gitlab CI for android

Tags: android, gitlab, flutter, code-signing, continuous-deployment

Dear stackoverflow community, once more I turn to you :)

I've recently come across the wonder of Gitlab and their very nice bundled CI/CD solution. It works gallantly however, we all need to sign our binaries don't we and I've found no way to upload a key as I would to a Jenkins server for doing this.

So, how can I, without checking in my keys and secrets sign my android (actually flutter) application when building a release?

From what I see, most people define the build job with signing settings referring to a non-committed key.properties file specifying a local keystore.jks. This works fine when building APKs locally but if I would like to build and archive them as a part of the CI/CD job, how do I?

For secret keys, for example the passwords to the keystore itself, I've found that I can simply store them as protected variables but the actual keystore file itself. What can I do about that?

Any ideas, suggestions are dearly welcome.
Cheers

Edit:
I apologise for never marking a right answer here and as @IvanP proposed the solution of writing individual values to a file was what I used for a long time. But as @VonC added later, Gitlab now has the capability to data as actual files which simplifies this so I am marking that as the correct answer.

Comment: You should look into App Signing inside the google play console.

Comment: I've seen that one but I didn't catch you can build without key. I expected you'll need an upload key or so anyway. I'll reread it and see if I can get it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you will still need a Keystore. But you can invalidate this keystore in the play console, if it gets leaked, because this one isn't your "real" keystore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [IvanP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407267/ivanp)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53434270):

> Usually I store keystore file (as base64 string), alias and passwords to Gitlab's secrets variables.

That should be easier with [GitLab 15.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/05/22/gitlab-15-0-released/#project-level-secure-files-in-open-beta) (May 2022)

> ### Project-level Secure Files in open beta
>
> Previously, it was difficult to use binary files in your CI/CD pipelines because CI/CD variables could only contain text values. This made it difficult to make use of profiles, certificates, keystores, and other secure information, which are important for teams building mobile apps.
>
> Today we are releasing Project-level Secure Files in [open beta](/handbook/product/gitlab-the-product/#open-beta). Now you can upload binary files to projects in GitLab, and include those files in CI/CD jobs to be used in the build and release processes as needed. Secure Files are stored outside of version control and are not part of the project repository.
>
> Please leave us your feedback about your experience with this feature in the [feedback issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/362407).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secure_files/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/346290).

Comment: Thank you @VonC, you are right this is definitely easier now and I am using the new file capability.

Comment: Thanks, @VonC, this is easier for sure. However, once you download the files they will remain in the repository unless you explicitly delete them. This means that, on a local gitlab runner, they will be kept on the machine until a new job cleans the repository. So, one could easily `cat` the files if they had permission to create a new job, right?

Comment: @TheFabbius I suppose so, yes (not tested). I suppose this is where a proper cleanup at the end of a job completion would be important.

Answer (score 53):

Usually I store keystore file (as base64 string), alias and passwords to Gitlab's secrets variables.

In the .gitlab-ci.yml do something like:

```
create_property_files:
  stage: prepare
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - echo $KEYSTORE | base64 -d > my.keystore
    - echo "keystorePath=my.keystore" > signing.properties
    - echo "keystorePassword=$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" >> signing.properties
    - echo "keyAlias=$ALIAS" >> signing.properties
    - echo "keyPassword=$KEY_PASSWORD" >> signing.properties
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - my.keystore
      - signing.properties
    expire_in: 10 mins
```

And, finally, in your build gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        file("../signing.properties").with { propFile ->
            if (propFile.canRead()) {
                def properties = new Properties()
                properties.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

                storeFile file(properties['keystorePath'])
                storePassword properties['keystorePassword']
                keyAlias properties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword properties['keyPassword']
            } else {
                println 'Unable to read signing.properties'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case you have all your sensitive data lying about in artifacts though, don't you ?

Comment: Yes, for 10 minutes. To prevent this, you can write signing.properties directly in build stage

Comment: How can I create the proper base64 version of my keystore?

Comment: On OS X try 'base64 -i <in-file> -o <outfile>'

Comment: I don't understand. What's the purpose of encrypting the keystore as base64 if anyone with the base64 program can decrypt it?

Comment: There is no security purpose in base64 encoding of the keystore. Because keystore has binary format, you can't put it into secret variable

Comment: does that mean you first convert the `my.keystore` file to base64 ?

Comment: for Linux users (tested with base64 (GNU coreutils) 8.30) use `base64 -i <in-file> > <outfile>`

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to @IvanP's answer but I had to make some changes in the Gitlab pipeline to get it working correctly.

Export the Keystore as a base64 string:

```
openssl base64 -A -in my.keystore > base64
```

Create a new variable and copy-paste the value in the file base64. Be careful while doing this, I screwed up the formatting and the pipeline was not able to decode the Keystore. The variables had to be referred to with ${} rather than just $.

```
- echo -n ${ANDROID_KEYSTORE} | base64 -d > my.keystore
- echo "keystorePath=../my.keystore" > myapp.properties
- echo "keystorePassword=${KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}" >> myapp.properties
- echo "keyAlias=${ALIAS_NAME}" >> myapp.properties
- echo "keyPassword=${KEY_PASSWORD}" >> myapp.properties
```

Refer to the myapp.properties in your build.gradle as explained above in the @IvanP's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [git-secret](http://git-secret.io/) in the past to check-in password protected secret files. Then pass the password via a [secret/protected environmental variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#variables) (as you already know) and modify the .gitlab-ci.yml to use the password to open the files and use them.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I've read in other places about using different repos and such to store the secret files. I'll give it a try and come back once it's done. Thank you!

Comment: Sure.. there is also a fastlane plugin that encrypts keystores https://github.com/hjanuschka/fastlane-plugin-cryptex (haven't tried). Plus here is a (dated) article about how NOT to manage certificates in Google Play Store https://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2014/08/bad-certificate-management-google-play-store/

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `android.injected` properties:

1. First encode the certificate file:

```
openssl enc -base64 -in certFile -out certFileEncoded
```

2. Get the content of `certFileEncoded` file and define in the Gitlab settings as a file type variable.
3. Inject certificate, alias and password in the assemble task:

```
script:
    - openssl enc -d -base64 -in $CERT_FILE_BASE_64 -out certFile
    - ./gradlew :app:assembleRelease -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=$(pwd)/certFile -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=$CERT_PASS -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=$CERT_ALIAS -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=$CERT_PASS
```

Here the `CERT_ALIAS` and `CERT_PASS` are masked variables.