# How set API key from signing.properties to index.html

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

To use Google Maps for web I need set API key as

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>
```

For Android I am using this technique showed in this thead:
[How to manage signing keystore in Gitlab CI for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51725339/how-to-manage-signing-keystore-in-gitlab-ci-for-android)

How can I get the Google Maps API key from signing.properties and set in index.html?